# To show principal value integral has order 1 as a distribution

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

To show principal value integral  has order 1 as a distribution

I have proved that $|p.v\int \frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx|\leq C\displaystyle\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1}|\partial^\alpha \phi|$ for some constant $C$

Now, this implies the order is at most 1, but how  can I prove that the order is not 0.

I am trying to use contradiction. Suppose its order is 0. Then for any compact set $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, there exist constant $C>0$ such that $$|p.v.\int\frac{\phi(x)}{x}dx|\leq C \sup|\phi|$$ for all $\phi\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $supp(\phi)\subseteq K$

But how to choose suitable $K$ and $\phi$ to get contradiction?

Comment: why $<pv(1/x),\phi_n>\rightarrow \infty$? How to get the result?

Comment: $\phi\in C^\infty_c([0,1]), \int\phi=1, \phi_n(x) = n\phi(nx), <pv(1/x),\phi_n \ast 1_{[1/n,1]}>\to \infty$. Equivalently $pv(1/x)=(\ln |x|)'$ if it was of order 0 then $\ln|x|$ would be bounded on bounded intervals. Additional question : what about $pv(x^{-1}\sin(1/x) )$

Comment: Sorry, I still have problem that how to get the estimation $<pv(1/x), \phi_n*1_{[1/n,1]}>\rightarrow \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $f_k : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_k(x) = \begin{cases}
kx, & |x| \leq \frac{1}{k} \\
\operatorname{sign}(x), & \frac{1}{k} \leq |x| \leq 1 \\
0, & 1 < |x|
\end{cases}
$$

Even if $f_k \not\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we can apply the definition of $\text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}$ on it:
$$
\langle \text{p.v.}\frac{1}{x}, f_k \rangle 
:= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1}{x} \, f_k(x) \, dx.
$$

What is the result? What is the limit as $k \to \infty$? What is $\sup |f_k|$?

And finally: How can we create a $\phi_k \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ that is close to $f_k$?

Comment: Let $\epsilon<\frac{1}{k}$, then $$\int_{|x|>\epsilon}\frac{1}{x}f_k(x)dx=\int_{-1}^{-1/k}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int_{-1/k}^{-\epsilon}kdx+\int^{1}_{1/k}\frac{1}{x}dx+\int^{1/k}_{\epsilon}kdx=-k\epsilon+1+1-k\epsilon=2-2k\epsilon$$ 

Hence,$<p.v.\frac{1}{x},f_k>=2$ right?

Comment: @Zoe. Sorry, I had made an error when $\frac{1}{k} \leq |x| \leq 1$.

Comment: but how to create $\phi_k\in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$? It that helpful to consider convolution with some function in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @Zoe. Yes, a convolution with a narrow $\rho \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $\int \rho(x) \, dx = 1$ will do it.

Comment: A short summary: $\sup |f_k| = 1$ while $\frac{1}{x} f_k \to \frac{1}{|x|}$ on $[-1,1]$ so $\int \frac{1}{x} f_j(x) \, dx \to \infty$ showing that $\frac{1}{x}$ can not be of order 0.